# Can't link external config file to FatJar in Ktor

Tags: kotlin, gradle, jar, gradlew, ktor

I generated a FatJar using the `./gradlew buildFatJar` command. However when I'm trying to run the .jar file under the "build/libs/" folder I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 

Neither port nor sslPort specified. Use command line options -port/-sslPort 
or configure connectors in application.conf
```

Even if I link the application.conf file (as described here: [ktor-dokumentation](https://ktor.io/docs/configuration-file.html#command-line) ) with the command: `java -jar app.jar -config=application.conf` the issue remains. (I copied the application.conf file next to the .jar file.)

(From the IntelliJ idea I can run the program without issue)

I did insert this to the build.gradle.kts file as described in the ktor deployment dokumentation:

```
ktor {
    fatJar {
        archiveFileName.set("WebhookUpdate.jar")
    }
}
```

Comment: I just found out that if I leave the argument like this: `-config=application.conf` it will split the name in the "." To pass the correct argument I need to change it to this: `-config="application.conf"`

However, it is still not solving the error.

Comment: So what problem is left?

Comment: The same issue remains. It can't recognize the configuration file when I run the .jar file with the arguments above.

Comment: I've answered in https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KTOR-6610